# Alternative to using between in a case statement in a where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm setting up reports, one for each month that'll auto-run daily (during/after the month in question), but I've ran into a roadblock with what'll happen during the current month. During the current month, we want the beginning of the month to today's date. Otherwise, run the report for the full month.

I'm currently trying the below, but it seems that 'between' can't be used in a case statement. Is there an easier way to do this or something I may be missing?

Thank you!

```
WHERE 1=1
AND CASE WHEN MONTH(getdate()) = '8' then OrderDate between '8/1/2023' and getdate())
else OrderDate between '8/1/2023' and '8/31/2023'
```

I tried many variations of this case statement but I kept running into a syntax error near the word between. After googling it, it seems that you can't use between in a case statement, but I can't figure out an alternative.

Comment: Your `CASE` doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: If Month = 8, get data from beginning of month till now.  Otherwise get data from beginning of month till end of month?

Comment: The case is meant to say, "When the current month is August, filter order date between august 1st and today. Otherwise, run for the full month (since it'd be running after August at this point)

Comment: So what's the parameter from the user?  A date or a month?

Answer (score 0):

[`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is an *expression* not a *statement* and as such can only return a scalar value, not an expression (which is explained in the documentation).

However you don't need a case expression here, just use regular AND/OR logic i.e.

```
AND ((
    MONTH(getdate()) = '8' AND OrderDate BETWEEN '8/1/2023' AND getdate())
) OR (
    MONTH(getdate()) <> '8' AND OrderDate BETWEEN '8/1/2023' AND '8/31/2023'
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the case when for both parts of of the BETWEEN

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE 1=1
AND OrderDate  BETWEEN CASE WHEN MONTH(getdate()) = '8' then   '8/1/2023' ELSE '8/1/2023' END 
AND 
CASE WHEN MONTH(getdate()) = '8' then
 getdate() ELSE 
   '8/31/2023' END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change into this:

```
WHERE 1=1
    AND OrderDate BETWEEN '20230801' and '20230831' -- Full month
    AND OrderDate <= getDate()
```

The second *AND* only limits during current month.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
WHERE 1=1 
AND ORDERDATE >= '2023-08-01' 
AND ORDERDATE < CASE 
                    WHEN MONTH(getdate()) = 8 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())
                    ELSE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, '2023-08-01')
                 END
```

Comment: A good answer explains how it works in addition to providing code.